# JSON to data frame in R

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I am trying to turn a .json file into a data frame for data visualization.

If I run the below code I get picture 1.

```
library(jsonlite)

jdata <- fromJSON("test.json")

data <- as.data.frame(jdata)
```

[image]

And when I try to transpose it, I get picture 2.

```
data2 <- as.data.frame(t(data))
```

[image]

This is how the json looks like raw:

[image]

I don't understand why column one has no name or is not part of the data frame (is jsonlite assuming these are tittles?). How can I overcome this?

I need a data frame from the json files:

Column1 (with the dates) | Column2 (I will divide it into values and coordinates

Comment: So, I got it to work with `dplyr`, but is there a way jsonlite can do this?

Comment: What does your json look like? If you look carefully you can see that in picture 1 the rows holding the timestamp doesn't have a name either

Comment: pictures aren't code or data unless image processing is the question. there are many examples of how to properly ask questions.

Comment: @derHugo the name of the whole file is "updates". I updated the question.

Comment: That's not a good formatted json than ... You don't have Variable names there but rather a different variable name for each update .... A better (and only usefull) way would look like `{"updates":[ {"time":"2017....", "value":"hello,....." },...]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this for the input file `test.json`

```
library(jsonlite)
jdata <- read_json("test.json", simplifyVector = TRUE)
```

Comment: @Prrarep Thanks!